# C++ getter/setter paradigm

Tags: c++, getter-setter, paradigms

I recently came across this class and was surprised at how the getters and 
setters were implemented.

I have not come across this before and would welcome some second opinions.

Do you think this is a good paradigm?
Is is bad?
Is it evil?

Header:

```
    class Tool
{
public:
    Tool();
    virtual ~Tool();

    bool setName(const std::string &name);
    bool getName(std::string &name) const;

    void clearName();

private:
    std::string m_name;
    bool m_nameSet;

};
```

cpp file:

```
#include "Tool.h"

Tool::Tool()
: m_name("")
, m_nameSet(false)
{
}


Tool::~Tool()
{
}


bool Tool::setName(const std::string &name)
{
    m_name = name;
    m_nameSet = true;
    return (m_nameSet);
}    

bool Tool::getName(std::string &name) const
{
    bool success = false;
    if (m_nameSet)
    {
        name = m_name;
        success = true;
    }
    return (success);
}
```

Comment: What do you refer to exactly as a good or bad paradigm? Storing information, whether name was set? That's clearly architecture-specific.

Answer (score 2):

The way you selected for getter is not popular, programmers prefer to `return` data from getter

```
std::string getName() const;
```

Why an item that set before, or has an initial data, should be re-checked on getter? If you want validate the data, validate it on setter.

However if your insist to return a value as "is name set before", you can write a third method by means of `bool isNameSet() const;`

Comment: _"If you want validate the data, validate it on setter."_ If the setter never gets called, how do you validate anything? How does the caller of the getter know if the value has been set or not?  (I don't know why the caller needs to know that, but apparently it does)

Comment: Ok, we can return a default value. and caller should check `isNameSet()` before. However all of these depend programmer's taste. I saw this pattern in Qt.

Answer (score 2):

This looks a lot like C where it is usual to return status codes to see if a functions fails or not.

Then also there are better methods to verify that a name is set or not. One could be to use the boost::optional to me this is a better way to declare intent that the name might not be set at all times.

I would however wonder if it's not better to make sure the name is set at all times by only having one constructor that takes a std::string as a parameter.

```
class Tool
{
public:
  //Constructor already does the right thing
  Tool() = default;
  virtual ~Tool();

  //Use void or return the modified class, akin to operators
  void setName(const std::string& name)
  {
    m_name = name;
  }
  //Alternatively
  Tool& setName(const std::string &name)
  {
    m_name = name;
    return *this;
  }

  //Return const reference to the value if possible, avoids copying if not needed
  //This will fail at run time if name is not set
  //Maybe throw an exception if that is preferred
  const std::string& getName() const
  {
    return *m_name;

    //Or

    if(m_name) return *m_name;
    else throw some_exception;
  }

  //Or return the optional, then calling code can check if name where set or not
  const boost::optional<std::string>& getName() const
  {
    return m_name;
  }


  void clearName()
  {
    m_name = boost::optional<std::string>();
  }

private:
  boost::optional<std::string> m_name;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call that a *paradigm*. This seems to be a solution for architecture, where a field may be in unspecified state (why not? Sometimes it is a sane requirement). Though, I don't like much this solution, because getter is supposed to return value (symmetrically, setter is supposed to set it) and the convention usually requires specific prototypes:

```
Type GetValue();
SetValue (const Type & newValue);
or
SetValue (Type & newValue);
or
SetValue (Type newValue);
```

You shall choose one of three setters depending on situation, usually the first or second one fits.

If a field may be in an unspecified state, I would choose another approach, as M M. suggests in his answer, I'll take liberty to provide an example:

```
class C
{
private:
    int field;
    bool fieldSet;

public:
    C()
    {
        field = 0;
        fieldSet = false;
    }

    bool IsFieldSet()
    {
        return fieldSet;
    }

    int GetField()
    {
        if (!fieldSet)
            throw std::exception("Attempt to use unset field!");

        return field;
    }

    void SetField(const int newValue)
    {
        field = newValue;
        fieldSet = true;
    }
};
```

Note though, that I wouldn't call this way of implementing getters *evil*. It may be just uncomfortable to use.